# Issues with C in realloc() or free() or double free or corruption

Tags: c

I am trying to capture audio packets of variable size, strip the RTP header, then concatenate the audio data to 20 bytes each.  My goal is to create something like a queue and just use pointer arithmetic to chop up data before I copy 20 bytes to a  buffer. The issue occurs when I get a large amount of audio bytes coming into the queue(probably greater than 20). Here is the while loop that captures, copies to queue, and chops up the data:

```
run_flag = TRUE;
    unsigned char *qs_ptr = NULL;  //the very start of the queue   
    unsigned char *qcur_ptr = NULL;       //the start of current audio packet
    unsigned char *qsa_ptr = NULL;   //the start of new incoming audio data 
    unsigned char *tmp_ptr = NULL; //points to the start of next audio packet to send
    unsigned char audio_buf[20];
    unsigned char buf[MAX_PACKET_LEN];
    unsigned char *pkt_no_hdr = NULL;
    int num_audio_bytes;
    int tot_bytes;
    int num_in_q;
    /* listen for voip packets */
    /* collection */

    /* keeps track of audio bytes, send data when = 20 */
    pf=fopen("rtp.dat","w");
    while (run_flag==TRUE) {
            if ((num_bytes = read(fd, buf, MAX_PACKET_LEN)) < 0) {
                    perror("recv");
                    close(sd);
                    exit(1);
            }
            pkt_no_hdr = (unsigned char *)calloc(num_bytes-12, sizeof(unsigned char));
            /* remove 12 rtp header bytes */
            num_audio_bytes = rem_rtp_hdr(pkt_no_hdr, &buf, num_bytes);
            print_bytes(pkt_no_hdr, num_bytes-12);
            printf("num audio bytes: %d\n", num_bytes-12);
            tot_bytes+=num_audio_bytes;
            num_in_q+=num_audio_bytes;
            printf("num_in_q: %d\n", num_in_q);
            cpy_to_q(&qs_ptr, &qcur_ptr, &qsa_ptr, pkt_no_hdr, num_audio_bytes, tot_bytes);
            free(pkt_no_hdr);
            if(num_in_q >= 20) {
                    tmp_ptr = qcur_ptr + 20;
                    memcpy(audio_buf, qcur_ptr, 20);
                    qcur_ptr = tmp_ptr;
                    print_bytes(audio_buf, 20);
                    // add header
                    // send mcast packet
                    num_in_q -= 20;
            }
    }
```

Here's the cpy_to_q function:

```
void cpy_to_q(unsigned char **qs_ptr, unsigned char **qcur_ptr, unsigned char **qsa_ptr, unsigned char *data, int num_bytes, int tot_bytes) {
    if(*qs_ptr == NULL) {
            *qs_ptr = (unsigned char *)malloc(num_bytes*sizeof(unsigned char) + 1);
            *qcur_ptr = *qs_ptr;
            *qsa_ptr = *qs_ptr;
            memcpy(*qs_ptr, data, num_bytes);
    } else {
            *qs_ptr = (unsigned char *)realloc(*qs_ptr, tot_bytes*sizeof(unsigned char) + 1);
            printf("size of q: %d\n", tot_bytes);
            *qsa_ptr += num_bytes;
            memcpy(*qsa_ptr, data, num_bytes);
    }
```

}

I keep getting errors related to `realloc()` or `free()` which must happen in the cpy_to_q function:

```
 \*** glibc detected \*** ./voipBridge: free(): invalid next size (fast):        0x000000000213b5b0 \***
```

Here is what valgrind says when the issue occurs:

```
Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable
==3799==    at 0x4C2B4F0: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)

==3799==    by 0x401211: cpy_to_q (handle_q.c:21)

==3799==    by 0x40177A: rcv_enter code herertp (net_interface.c:142)

==3799==    by 0x401D89: main (voip_bridge.c:48)
```

Here is what the log says before the issue:

```
num audio bytes: 6 n
num_in_q: 14
REALLOC
size of q: 94
bytes: 0bd2d4b5da0f
num audio bytes: 6
num_in_q: 20
REALLOC
size of q: 100
bytes: b15c0f0b86f3b15a0f0bd2d4b5da0f0000000000
bytes: 08cb24ad9a0f
num audio bytes: 6
num_in_q: 6
REALLOC
size of q: 106 
bytes: 22c6a0d000e3980ba0f27ccca4336ef243e3168e57150fd6e388b8c7bf
num audio bytes: 29
num_in_q: 35
REALLOC
size of q: 135
*** glibc detected *** ./voipBridge: double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000023432f0 ***
```

Also, I realize the queue will just keep getting larger and larger.  Is there a way to free up memory without freeing the entire block?

Thanks.

Comment: C++ and C can be very different. Does this question really apply to both?

Comment: not really.  Just C.  But I figured someone with C++ knowledge might also understand the question.

Comment: Any chance you could reduce this to a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a significant problem:

```
void cpy_to_q(unsigned char **qs_ptr, unsigned char **qcur_ptr, unsigned char **qsa_ptr, 

    unsigned char *data, int num_bytes, int tot_bytes) {
        if(*qs_ptr == NULL) {
                *qs_ptr = (unsigned char *)malloc(num_bytes*sizeof(unsigned char) + 1);
                *qcur_ptr = *qs_ptr;
                *qsa_ptr = *qs_ptr;
                memcpy(*qs_ptr, data, num_bytes);
        } else {
                // HERE YOU REALLOC THE BASE PTR, BUT DON"T REPOS THE CUR PTR
                *qs_ptr = (unsigned char *)realloc(*qs_ptr, tot_bytes*sizeof(unsigned char) + 1);
                printf("size of q: %d\n", tot_bytes);
                *qsa_ptr += num_bytes;
                memcpy(*qsa_ptr, data, num_bytes);
        }
    }
```

When the allocation finally becomes significant enough to warrant a new full page alloc, `realloc()` will work, but now you have a current-pointer still pointing to an old queue that doesn't even exist anymore.

To fix this, keep the delta from the current queue in a tmp size var, then base the *new* cur_ptr off the *new* queue-base after the realloc. The same housekeeping logic is needed for the sa ptr, btw.

So something like this, and note this assumes your list always *grows* and has an entirely separate `reset()` or `shrink()` mechanism.

```
void cpy_to_q
(
    unsigned char **qs_ptr,
    unsigned char **qcur_ptr,
    unsigned char **qsa_ptr,
    unsigned char *data,
    int num_bytes,
    int tot_bytes
)
{
    if(*qs_ptr == NULL)
    {
        *qs_ptr = malloc(num_bytes*sizeof(unsigned char) + 1);
        *qcur_ptr = *qs_ptr;
        *qsa_ptr = *qs_ptr;
        memcpy(*qs_ptr, data, num_bytes);
    }
    else
    {
        size_t cur_diff = *qcur_ptr - *qs_ptr;
        size_t sa_diff = *qsa_ptr - *qs_ptr;

        // now realloc (note: you really should error check this)
        *qs_ptr = realloc(*qs_ptr, tot_bytes*sizeof(unsigned char) + 1);
        printf("size of q: %d\n", tot_bytes);

        // now reposition your old pointers.
        *qcur_ptr = *qs_ptr + cur_diff;
        *qsa_ptr = *qs_ptr + sa_diff;

        // and finally continue as before
        *qsa_ptr += num_bytes;
        memcpy(*qsa_ptr, data, num_bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that realloc will move the qs_ptr to a new location entirely when the allocation size becomes too large?

Comment: @jbrew larger, smaller, makes no different; thats exactly what it *can* do. **Everything** that is also a pointer into that current buffer needs to be reconfigured to the new buffer when that realloc is done, otherwise you have undefined behavior. Consider yourself fortunate that you just happened to be passing all your management pointers. It should make the adjustment fairly local (note: the sample above is your `else` block from your code, I hope you understood that).

Comment: Oh I see what you're are saying then.  I made the changes and I still get: *** glibc detected *** ./voipBridge: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001314490 ***.  It happened when I got 29 audio bytes followed by 39.  It works fine before that.

Comment: @jbrew then there is another issue in your code managing the queue pointers, but this is none-the-less dire. Also note if you have any data pointers referencing the queue-data block outside of this they, likewise, must be assumed-invalid after a realloc. for the queue processing logic I would have to stare at it awhile.

Comment: It seems to be working a lot better than before, so I assume there are similar issues elsewhere like you mentioned.  The behavior is strange because sometimes it will continue and if I stop and restart the program it will fail right away.  Thanks for your help, I will accept.